# if condition onclick - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.product-nav li a').click(function() {
  $('.product-nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  if( $(this).hasClass('tshirts') ){
    $('product').hide();
    $('.product.tshirt').show();
  }
});
```

.. active class is assigned correctly but the products are not hidden/shown as desired because I think the if condition is not recognized on click?

Comment: It looks like you may have an issue with `$('product').hide();` -- try `$('.product').hide();`.  See the missing period to make it a class selector?

Comment: If product was an id, then this: $('product').hide(); should be corrected to this: $('#product').hide(); can you show your html?

Comment: Need more reference where is tshirts? Right now you are saying it is on the anchor. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What element is product?

```
$('product').hide();
```

You are missing the `.`

```
$('.product').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't have a problem reaching your condition.

You seem to have a typo though. On line #5, you're running a jQuery selector for `<product>` elements. Do you mean to select elements with the class `product`? (i.e. `$('.product')`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.product-nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

The 1st line removes it, the 2nd line adds it back in.

Do you mean:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('tshirts');
```

Comment: No, the first line removes the class from ALL of the LIs, the second line only adds it to the parent of the a that was clicked.

Comment: this may be false alarm if OP has, for example, the following hierarchy .product-nav > li > div > a